# Motion estimation in Video Compression

Tags: compression

I have a question related to the title above. From what ive read, the theory of this techinique is to take a previous reference frame and make an estimation of the current frame based on the reference frame. Then, on a block by block basis, search for a match in the reference frame with regard to the prediction in the current frame. Then you get a motion vector between the reference frame and the current frame. This doesnt really make sense to me though because at the end of it all you are still only getting a vector between the true reference frame (i say true because i'l assume its the first spatially intra coded reference frame) and a predicted frame. Can someone please explain to me if im understanding the technique wrong??

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Motion estimation result is typically more than just a "motion vector between reference frame and current frame". This part is called "global motion compensation", and indeed has some dedicated algorithms for it at frame level. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Global_motion_compensation

However, the idea of motion estimation is more than that. It is to find a moving element into an image, which means that even if the "frame" doesn't move, you still want to detect a car into the frame which moves from left to right.
This part is done "block by block", and is called "Block motion compensation".

Hence, the motion estimation result is a serie of vectors, provided for groups a small pixels blocks (typically 16x16 for MPEG, or even 4x4 for H264 (although the layout is really complex for this last one)).